# how do i download the csv file from a website using python code for my jupyter notebook

Tags: python, api, csv, web-scraping, data-science

I want to download the daily data about the daily covid19 cases from the ECDC Website. How do I do that with python code and import it to my notebook.
I have previously downloaded the data from GitHub, but I have no idea how to download the data from a link provided on a live website.

```
from github.MainClass import Github
g = Github('KEY')
repo = g.get_repo("CSSEGISandData/COVID-19")
file_list = repo.get_contents("csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports")
github_dir_path = 'https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/raw/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/'
file_path = github_dir_path  + str(file_list[-2]).split('/')[-1].split(".")[0]+ '.csv'
```

Comment: What is the URL of the live website from which you want to download the data?

Comment: `pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-22-2020.csv')` Try using the raw path.

Answer (score 1):

I was just able to use this and download it. Is your issue getting the list of files or you are unaware that you can use URLs in `read_csv`

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-22-2020.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, error_bad_lines = False)
```

Comment: How do i download the data from [ECDC](https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/en/publications-data/download-todays-data-geographic-distribution-covid-19-cases-worldwide)  instead of this github repo

Comment: @YoDa - Just replace the URL with whichever file you want downloaded